# Creating a hollow diamond in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a hollow diamond in C and here's what I currently have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
       int n, a = 1, x, y;

       printf("Enter size: ");
       scanf("%d", &n);

       a = n - 1;

       for(x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
              for(y = 1; y <= a; y++) printf(" ");

              a--;

              for(y = 1; y <= 2*x-1; y++) printf("*");

              printf("\n");
       }

       a = 1;

       for(x = 1; x <= n-1; x++) {
              for (y = 1; y <= a; y++) printf(" ");

              a++;

              for (y = 1; y <= 2*(n-x)-1; y++) printf("*");

              printf("\n");
       }
}
```

As you can see, it prints out a diamond, but not a hollow one. Any help?

Comment: What is 'size' supposed to represent? The width at the widest point, or the height at the tallest?

Comment: Missing `int` for `main()`. Initialization of `a` not used. `scanf()` return code not tested. One line loops without `{}`. No return value for `main()`. Oh, the humanity...

Comment: @DevSolar: one-line-loops without {} are ok, as long as they are not empty loops. And since C99, `return 0` is implicit for `main` if the end of the function is reached (Of course, C99 banned implicit `int`, so an error either way).

Comment: @Deduplicator: While nothing I listed (except for the missing return type for `main()` is a formal error, it's certainly enough to make this an immediate "fail" in any kind of code review I've ever been involved in. I just thought I'd point this out while the OP is still in a mindset to change his ways.

Comment: Instead of writing consecutive `'*'` in a `for` loop, write one `'*'`, then a sequence of `' '` and then again a `'*'`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to output something like this,

```
....#....
...###...
..#####..
.###x###.
###x x###
.###x###.
..#####..
...###...
....#....
```

by far the easiest approach is to iterate over 0 <= x <= size, 0 <= y <= size,
and determine by the *Manhattan Distance* of the coordinate (x,y) - (size/2, size/2),
if the point is within at the perimeter. Making an equation *MIN* <= *distance* <= *MAX*, one can control the thickness of the diamond.

```
void diamond(int size)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
      printf("%c", (abs(i - size/2) + abs(j - size/2)) == (size / 2) ? '#' : ' ');
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Four minor changes,

```
for(y = 1; y <= 2*x-1; y++) printf("*");
printf("\n");
```

Should be something like,

```
for(y = 1; y < 2*x-1; y++) printf((y == 1) ? "*" : " ");
printf("*\n");
```

And,

```
for (y = 1; y <= 2*(n-x)-1; y++) printf("*");
printf("\n");
```

Should also be something like,

```
for (y = 1; y < 2*(n-x)-1; y++) printf((y == 1) ? "*" : " ");
printf("*\n");
```

When I make those changes your program prints a *hollow* diamond.

Comment: Also advisable, using explicit `int` return-type (not mandatory pre-C99).